# Error in C++ setting up a server to use with telnet client

Tags: c++, networking, telnet

Hey guys like title says im getting an error in my Server when trying to connect to telnet.  Im getting this error:

```
Error   1   error C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings
```

Now i understand that this error is telling me i need to use inet_pton because it is newer as i found out online.  Unfortunately i cant find the web page i was on.  But im having problems getting this integrated into my code.  This even has the lecturer working on a solution.

Here is my code guys:

```
// MUD Programming
// Ron Penton
// (C)2003
// SocketLibSystem.cpp - This header contains all of the socket functions
// that aren't related to any classes.

#include "SocketLibSystem.h"
#include "SocketLibErrors.h"

// this is a simple object-oriented socket library wrapper around
// winsock/BSDsockets. It will only use TCP/IP as it's method of communication,
// and will have no UDP support at all.
namespace SocketLib
{


    // ========================================================================
    //  This class is designed to be a global singleton that initializes
    //  and shuts down Winsock.
    // ========================================================================
    #ifdef WIN32                // windows 95 and above
        class System
        {
        public:
            // ================================================================
            //  This initializes winsock
            // ================================================================
            System()
            {
                // attempt to start up the winsock lib
                WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &m_WSAData );
            }

            // ========================================================================
            //  This shuts down winsock
            // ========================================================================
            ~System()
            {
                // attempt to close down the winsock lib
                WSACleanup();
            }

        protected:
            // holds information about winsock
            WSADATA m_WSAData;
        };

        System g_system;
    #endif


    // ========================================================================
    // Function:    GetIPAddress
    // Purpose:     To get the IP address of the string as an ipaddress
    //              structure. Throws an exception if the address cannot be
    //              converted.
    // ========================================================================
    ipaddress GetIPAddress( const std::string p_address )
    {

        if( IsIPAddress( p_address ) )
        {
            // if the address is just a regular IP address, there's no need
            // to do a DNS lookup, so just convert the string directly into
            // its binary format.
            ipaddress addr = inet_addr( p_address.c_str() );
            //inet_pton(AF_INET, addr, buf);

            // if the address is invalid, throw a HOST_NOT_FOUND exception.
            if( addr == INADDR_NONE )
            {
                throw Exception( EDNSNotFound );
            }

            // by this point, the address is valid, so return it.
            return addr;
        }
        else
        {
            // the address isn't an IP address, so we need to look it up using
            // DNS. 
            struct hostent* host = gethostbyname( p_address.c_str() );

            // if there was an error, throw an exception.
            if( host == 0 )
            {
                // get the error from h_errno.
                throw Exception( GetError( false ) );
            }

            // now perform some really wierd casting tricks to get the value.
            // h_addr is a char*, so cast it into an ipaddress*, and 
            // dereference it to get the value.
            return *((ipaddress*)host->h_addr);
        }
    }


    // ========================================================================
    // Function:    GetIPString
    // Purpose:     Converts an ipaddress structure to a string in numerical
    //              format.
    // ========================================================================
    std::string GetIPString( ipaddress p_address )
    {
        // return a new string containing the address.
        // (god that is some ugly casting going on... stupid language)
        char* str = inet_ntoa( *((in_addr*)&p_address) );
        if( str == 0 )
        {
            return std::string( "Invalid IP Address" );
        }
        return std::string( str );
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Function:    GetHostNameString
    // Purpose:     Converts an ipaddress structure to a string using
    //              reverse-DNS lookup. This may block.
    // ========================================================================
    std::string GetHostNameString( ipaddress p_address )
    {
        // get the host info.
        struct hostent* host = gethostbyaddr( (char*)&p_address, 4, AF_INET );

        // if there was an error, throw an exception.
        if( host == 0 )
        {
            // get the error from h_errno.
            throw Exception( GetError( false ) );
        }

        return std::string( host->h_name );
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Function:    IsIPAddress
    // Purpose:     determines if a string contains a pure numerical IP address
    //              (returns true) or a DNS'able address (returns false)
    // ========================================================================
    bool IsIPAddress( const std::string p_address )
    {
        // scan through the string to see if it's a pure IP address or not.
        // basically, we assume that any string with characters other than
        // numerics and periods needs to be DNS'ed.
        for( size_t i = 0; i < p_address.length(); i++ )
        {
            if( ( p_address[i] < '0' || p_address[i] > '9' ) && 
                p_address[i] != '.' )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }




}
```

Ive pasted the whole cpp file just incase its needed for a solution.  Any help is appreciated guys.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But im having problems getting this integrated into my code." What have you tried, what problems are you getting?

Comment: using the inet_pton function we added (AF_NET, p_address.c_str(),and im not entirely sure what my lecturer put in buffer but p_address gave out a similar error saying to use something else

Comment: _"but p_address gave out a similar error saying to use something else"_ You're going to have to be a lot more precise and scientific than that if you want free help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ipaddress GetIPAddress( const std::string p_address )
{
    if( IsIPAddress( p_address ) )
    {
        // if the address is just a regular IP address, there's no need
        // to do a DNS lookup, so just convert the string directly into
        // its binary format.

        // if the address is invalid, throw a HOST_NOT_FOUND exception.
        IN_ADDR addr;
        if( inet_pton(AF_INET, p_address.c_str(), &addr) != 1 )
        {
            throw Exception( EDNSNotFound );
        }

        // by this point, the address is valid, so return it.
        return addr.s_addr;
    }
    else
    {
        // the address isn't an IP address, so we need to look it up using DNS. 
        struct hostent* host = gethostbyname( p_address.c_str() );

        // if there was an error, throw an exception.
        if( !host )
        {
            // get the error from h_errno.
            throw Exception( GetError( false ) );
        }

        // make sure it is IPv4
        if( host->h_addrtype != AF_INET )
        {
            throw Exception( EDNSNotFound );
        }

        // now perform some really wierd casting tricks to get the value.
        // h_addr is a char*, so cast it into an in_addr*, and 
        // dereference it to get the value.

        return *((in_addr*)(host->h_addr));
    }
}
```

With that said, you really should use `getaddrinfo()` instead of `inet_pton()` and `gethostbyname()`:

```
ipaddress GetIPAddress( const std::string p_address )
{
    // if the address is just a regular IP address, there's no need
    // to do a DNS lookup, so just convert the string directly into
    // its binary format.

    addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_flags = IsIPAddress( p_address ) ? AI_NUMERICHOST : 0;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    // if the address is invalid, throw a HOST_NOT_FOUND exception.
    addrinfo *addrs = NULL;
    if( getaddrinfo( p_address.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &addrs ) != 0 )
    {
        throw Exception( EDNSNotFound );
    }

    // by this point, the address is valid, so return it.

    // now perform some really wierd casting tricks to get the value.
    // ai_addr is a sockaddr*, so cast it to an sockaddr_in*, and 
    // dereference it to get the value.

    ipaddress addr = ((sockaddr_in*)(addrs->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
    freeaddrinfo(addrs);

    return addr;
}
```

And use `getnameinfo()` instead of `gethostbyaddr()` in `GetHostNameString()` (an optionally instead of `inet_ntoa()` in `GetIPString()`):

```
std::string GetHostNameString( ipaddress p_address )
{
    char host[NI_MAXHOST+1] = {0};

    struct sockaddr_in addr = {0};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = p_address;

    // get the host info.

    // if there was an error, throw an exception.
    if( getnameinfo( (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0 ) != 0 )
    {
        throw Exception( EDNSNotFound );
    }

    return std::string( host );
}
```